# Kendo MultiSelect update of ngmodel

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model, kendo-multiselect

I'm trying to add one button for adding values to ngmodel of kendo's multi select:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select id='my' kendo-multi-select k-options="selectOptions" k-ng-model="selectedIds"></select>
  <p ng-show="selectedIds.length">Selected: {{ selectedIds }}</p>
  <button ng-click="addSelectedId()">Add selected id</button>
  <input ng-model="enteredId" />
</div>
```

Here is controller

```
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.selectOptions = {
          placeholder: "Select products...",
          dataTextField: "ProductName",
          dataValueField: "ProductID",
          autoBind: false,
          dataSource: {
              type: "odata",
              serverFiltering: true,
              transport: {
                  read: {
                      url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
                  }
              }
          }
      };
      $scope.selectedIds = [ 4, 7];
       $scope.addSelectedId = function() {
          $scope.selectedIds.push(parseInt($scope.enteredId));
          console.log($scope.selectedIds);
       };
  }
```

Plunker is here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EH0EaMhFsV2JTdwpkqGg?p=preview

When added to selectedIds, nothing gets added to dropdown select placeholder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add k-rebind="selectedIds" in your html code

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select id='my' kendo-multi-select k-options="selectOptions" k-ng-model="selectedIds" k-rebind="selectedIds"></select>
  <p ng-show="selectedIds.length">Selected: {{ selectedIds }}</p>
  <button ng-click="addSelectedId()">Add selected id</button>
  <input ng-model="enteredId" />
</div>
```

[Please see this updated plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/atE9ATu91L0RVo87AmMV?p=preview)